# IIS URL Rewrite URLwith Optional Index Page

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, iis-7

I've been able to pattern-match a url with or without a trailing slash

```
<match url="locations/(.+?)/?$" />
```

However, I want to be able to match locations/[location]/index.aspx as well.

How can I incorporate this optional pattern?

I tried the clumsy:

```
<match url="(towns/(.+?)/?$)|(towns/(.+?)/index\.aspx$)" />
```

which wasn't liked at all!

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you ask is unclear. `.+?` matches `index.aspx`, thus adding an alternative as the second one won't make any difference.

Comment: Sorry I'm not very good at regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
(?<=locations\/)(.+?)(?=\/|$|\s)
```

will match [location] in

```
/locations/[location]/
/locations/[location]
/locations/[location]/index.aspx
/locations/[location]/anything_on_the_planet.html
/locations/[location] <A bunch of text over here>
```

If I am understanding your question right you want -

1. with or without trailing slash
2. To follow locations/
3. to work regardless what is on the other side of the [location]

If you need anything else, let me know